# Customise top bar of an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to customise the top bar of an iPhone application (not a website)? If so, how can I change the background colour to orange?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the very top bar (with the wifi-strength etc) then it's impossible following the AppStore-rules. You can change it to black only.

It's however possible with various jailbreak-tools, but then you can't publish your app to app store.

Comment: If he's talking about the status bar which shows the time, you're correct (although he can hide that of course, and display something else), but I think he's talking about a navigation bar or tool bar.

Comment: If you are taking about the statusbar you can choose between original, hiding it, black and translucent black. You could try using translucent black and putting orange color in the view underneath it. I think thats the closest you'll get to colouring it..

Comment: Let's hope he is. I figured your answer was enough if that's the case. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm guessing here you could be talking about a `UINavigationBar` or a `UIToolBar`, but that doesn't really matter because yes, you can change the colour of either.

In Interface Builder, select the `UINavigationBar` (or `UIToolBar`) and under properties look at "tint".  This will be set to "default" initially.  You can then pick any colour (even orange!) as the tint colour, and there you go!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using the tintColor property of the navigation bar.
I have implemented and checked it. its working.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
```

hAPPY cODING...